# Creating an SMS server on the PC

Tags: java-me, mobile, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to create an application that would act as an SMS server between multiple virtual instances of Java ME.

I have searched online and have not found anything that dealt with this issue.
This is not to be confused with the link attached that was discussed on stack overflow before.
[J2ME SMS Server on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914627/j2me-sms-server-on-mobile-phone)

I am hoping to create the SMS Server to act as a tester for an actual SMS gateway in a production environment.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible with j2me
for testing you have to create two application.

In which one application will send sms to a phone no on predefine port and 
the receiver application will listen on that port for incoming sms

go through [this](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/03/start-application-using-pushregistry.html) sample code it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I am aware to simulate services provided by the service provide such as Cell Broadcast Services.
Or the ability for the phone to send a text to a service on the PC and copy the message to all virtual subscribers like a multicast for SMS

I am aware that java provides the package "javax.wireless.messaging" but I am wondering if its specific to ME